# How to split columns based on field title

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am working with a single warehouse table with columns like "2015 Fee", "2015 Revenue", "2016 Fee", "2016 Revenue", etc. I need to split these out into "Revenue", "Fee", and "Billed Year" in order to do some analysis. Many of the records have fee and revenue in multiple years.

The CASE statement I tried only pulls in the first year, but I need it to pull in all years.

Here's my case statements:

```
    (CASE when 2015_revenue IS NOT NULL then 2015_revenue
        when 2016_revenue_$ IS NOT NULL then 2016_revenue
       END) as revenue,
(CASE when 2015_fee IS NOT NULL then 2015_fee
    when 2016_fee IS NOT NULL then 2016_fee
  END) as fee, 
(CASE when 2015_revenue IS NOT NULL then '2015'
        when 2015_fee IS NOT NULL then '2015'
        when 2016_revenue IS NOT NULL then '2016'
        when 2016_fee IS NOT NULL then '2016'
        end) as bill_year
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to write this sql out because the schema is bad. :/

Comment: Can you please Edit your question to provide some sample rows for the input data and an example of the output you would like from the query? We will then be able to offer some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a CASE statement, it's creating a temp table with UNIONs and joining to that:

```
    SELECT p1.[bunch of fields from table]
    amts.fee
    amts.revenue
    amts.bill_year
    FROM table p1
    JOIN (SELECT id, 2015_revenue as revenue, 2015_fee as fee, '2015' as bill_year FROM table
           UNION
           SELECT id, 2016_revenue as revenue, 2016_fee as fee, '2016' as bill_year FROM table
           U) amts on amts.id = p1.id;
```